# How to run Tensorflow clustering algorithm model

Tags: tensorflow, go, k-means

I need to run k-means algorithm from Tensorflow in Go, i.e. cluster a graph intro subgraphs according to nodes similarity matrix.

I came across [this article](https://www.tonytruong.net/running-a-keras-tensorflow-model-in-golang/) which shows an example on how to run a Keras  trained model in Go. In this example the algo is of a supervised learning type. However in clustering algos, as I understand, there will be no model to save and export it to Go implementation.

The reason I am interested in Tensorflow, is because I think its code is optimized and will run much faster than [k-mean implementation](https://github.com/mpraski/clusters) in Go, even with the scenario I described above.

I need an opinion of whether:

1. It is indeed impossible to use a Tensorflow k-mean algorithm in Go, and it is much better just to use k-means implemented in Go for this case.
2. It is possible to do this, and some sort of example or ideas on how to do this are very much appreciated.

Comment: http://marubon-ds.blogspot.com/2017/08/kmeans-by-golang.html looks really helpful, has a code example.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I saw that article when investigating this topic. The reason I posted here this question is that I want to you Tensorflow bindings for Go to run kmeans. Apparently this is not possible, and I want someone to either confirm this here or dispute by an example.